# How can I make these sharp, pressed in parts of a burger?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, sculpting

I have tried using the *Draw Sharp* tool to achieve this, but unfortunately, as it is visible, it's really hard to achieve this "peel" sort of look, where it looks really sharp. How can I achieve this?

Is this to be done by some sculpting tool, or is this to be done using texturing/shading?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could simply use the photo as texture, paint on the surface with the stencil option  ;)

Comment: @moonboots great idea! Could you post this as an answer for others to see clearly?

Comment: ok, done.....  ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Textures, shading, and normal maps can help a lot with the effect. However I have a different tip that can help, especially (but not exclusively) if you happen to use the subdivision surface modifier as part of your workflow. This works as a complement to using the sculpt tool, or just moving vertices around manually.

(Sorry if this isn't what you're looking for or it's too detailed - but maybe it can help somebody else who happens to find this post!)

Before you've applied the subdivision modifier, you can select specific edges and mark them as edge creases.

Here is a weird little character thing for demonstration:

[image]

And here is a preview of what it would look like (so far) when the subdivision modifier is applied. It's too soft and rounded:

[image]

Select the edges you want to be creased:

[image]

Press ctrl + E to open the edge menu and choose "edge crease" (or press shift + E to use edge crease immediately):

[image]

Then drag your cursor back and forth to play around, or use the window that appears in the bottom left corner to configure how extreme you want to get:

[image]

Here's the extra pointy boi:

[image]

As long as those edges are still marked when you hit "apply" on the modifier, they will stay in the final result! (You'll see I added another sharp crease here)

[image]

Even if you don't have any modifiers, if your edges are still marked as creased, and you enter sculpting mode, they stay pretty crispy:

[[image: after some sculpting, the edges still remain sharp looking][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijCCj.png)

Comment: This technically _is_ what I want. Thanks, I totally forgot about modelling. Though you could also edit your answer to include the **pinch** tool in sculpt mode, which also helps do this.

Answer (score 7):

You could paint a bread texture on your object, with the *Draw* brush, *Mapping > Stencil*:

- Unwrap your object with the *Smart UV Project* option
- Create a material, plug an *Image Texture* into the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF*, create a new (black) image
- Find a burger image that is not too contrasted
- Switch to *Texture Paint* mode, keep the *Draw* brush selected, open the *N* panel, and under *Tool > Brush Settings > Texture*, click on the button on the right (*Show texture in texture tab*) and in the Texture panel open the burger image, and choose *Mapping > Stencil*:

[image]

- You'll see the image in the 3D view, right click to move it, right click + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to scale, right click + <kbd>Alt</kbd> to rotate, paint on your object, choose about the same perspective as in the image:

[image]

- Lower down the *Specular* of the *Principled BSDF*. You can convert your texture image to a normal map to have more 3D relief. Also you can sculpt your object a bit

Comment: A +1! Though I considered accepting this instead, however, this would be hard to achieve if we wanted to use an approach where texturing can't be used or the specific texture is not available. Anyways, thanks for the answer!)

Comment: sure, this is the easy and lazy solution, but sometimes why not  ;)

Comment: Yeah, I will surely keep this in mind when I have a tight deadline ;)

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to Sleepysheepy and Moonboots's great answers, there is a sculpting tool called the ***Multi-Pane Scrape***, which basically kind of pinches the mesh together, and creates the desired effect of the question. It presses down the right and left parts, and sharply takes up the centre part, just as though it was a peel or something.[image]